# I can't bake the texture: "Baking map saved to internal image, save it externally or pack it"

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking, vector-mapping

Hello I just started to testing "baking". I created "BaseColor" texture and I joined everything on one model, pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd> *Apply > Scale & Rotation* and Smart UV.

After the editing I added UV and Env texture to every material and baked it but my Base Color texture is black.

[image: Smart UV]

Smart UV

[image: UV and Env Texture.]

UV and Env Texture.

[image: info after bake]

Info after bake

[image: base color texture in the end.]

```
base color texture in the end.
```

Blender File: https://we.tl/t-QVn7waFCie

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/218408/2214 or here for multi-object bake https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91526/baking-multiple-materials-into-one-texture ... BTW it doesn't make a sense to use Environmental texture node :)

Comment: thank you so much @vklidu i closed the blender and opened and my problem has been solved and can you tell me what diff. that have env and Image tex?