# Merge 2 objects and appending theirs texture's and UV in to one

Tags: texturing, uv

so let say that I have 2 objects which are imported to blender and I want to add them together so I have one solid mesh but how can I append theirs textures and UV's in order to have everything in one texture (so merge 2 texture's in to one) and merge UV's also ?

Comment: You need to bake the 2 image textures on one

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57944/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/168511/2214 https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/218408/2214